# javascript get parameters when hover href inside a loop

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, dom, servlets

I have the following problem:

```
var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();   //xmlhttp holds the ajax object

$(function() {
$('a.popper').hover(function(e) {


 if(xmlhttp) {

xmlhttp.open("GET","DokterWeek_KlantoverzichtServlet?" + $("a.popper").prop("href").split("?")[1],true);//gettime will be the servlet name
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Above you can see I get the parameters for my servlet when I hover over the a href class="popper" which works..
But the problem is that it always gets the LAST "a href" parameters in the foreach loop...

```
 <c:forEach items="${row}" var="cell">

<a href="./DokterWeek_KlantoverzichtServlet?AfspraakID=${cell.afspraakId}&Id=${cell.id}&KlantId=${cell.klant.id}" 
class="popper" data-popbox="pop1">

<c:forEach items="${row}" var="cell">
```

Is there any javascript or jquery possibility that I can get the a href value LIVE when i hover over it... when I hover over these links my browser sees the parameters changing, but javascript won't fetch it.. Javascript takes the first or the last ahref in the loop...

Pls help me, I have been searching for a solution for more then 2 days :(

Comment: can you share which event is trigering the ajax request

Comment: You should probably share the complete code

Comment: pls take a look again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to get the `href` of the hovered element. This can be done using `$(this)`

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","DokterWeek_KlantoverzichtServlet?" + $(this).prop("href").split("?")[1],true);//gettime will be the servlet name
```

**Note:**
Since you are using jQuery please use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) utility to make ajax calls instead of using raw `XmlHTTPRequest`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not getting the href value of the element your hovering. You can use `$(this)` to do that. In your case, you use the `$("a.popper")`, which gets all the `a.popper` elements, thus selecting the last href.

In your case:

```
var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();   //xmlhttp holds the ajax object

$(function() {
$('a.popper').hover(function(e) {
    var theElementYourHovering = $(this),
        currentHref = theElementYourHovering.attr('href');

    // Do your stuff here
}
```